# My answer got deleted - But why?

Tags: support, status-completed

[How can I disable the drag handle on the desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/505188/how-can-i-disable-the-drag-handle-on-the-desktop)

Backstory:

- Could not find the previous question via Google (site:superuser.com) and through Superuser's own search.
- Made my own question.
- Found the answer by myself, so I answered my own question.
- Soon the "it may be a duplicate" votes appeared.
- So I flagged my question to be deleted (for moderator)
- Answered the old question

And for some reason...

- My question did not get removed.
- The answer I posted to the old question got deleted.

Why?

Comment: Probably a miscommunication/misunderstanding on behalf of the mods, unless they disagreed with the dupe close votes and wanted to keep the question around.

Answer (score 8):

Your flag said,

> A duplicate, would be better if the whole thing would get removed. (Only I answered anyway. So...yeah.)

Maybe that was misunderstood by the mod who handled it. I also had to read it twice. We're all humans, remember. Maybe you could have written something like:

> Please delete my question. It's a duplicate of an older post, and I already added my answer there.

Or something along those lines. Basically, the more direct you are when flagging (i.e., telling mods what they should do), the better the chances of not being misunderstood.

That being said <s>I deleted your question and undeleted your answer</s> I kept the question as-is (it serves as an anchor for people who might use different words to look up the problem), and Sathya came in first to undelete the answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was pretty sick yesterday, could not even think straight, sorry. You are right. (Yet, I had to post that answer. Oh well.)